# Probability of two events related to a statement of the form "P implies Q"

Tags: probability

Let the probability space be $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Let For every $\omega \in \Omega$, $P(\omega) \Rightarrow Q(\omega)$ where $P,Q$ are two expressions.

Can we claim that $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega: P(\omega)\}) \leq \mathbb{P}(\{\omega: Q(\omega)\})  $?

Notes:

1. $P(\omega) \Rightarrow Q(\omega)$ means "if $P$ then $Q$" or "$P$ is sufficient to conclude $Q$" or "$Q$ is necessary for $P$"
2. A related question is: is $\{\omega: P(\omega)\} \subseteq \{\omega: Q(\omega)\}$?
3. Example of expressions: $P(\omega)$ can be $ \mathbb{E}_{z_1}[f(z_1,\omega)] \geq 0, \mathbb{E}_{z_2}[f(z_2,\omega)] \geq 0$ where $z_1,z_2$ are independent Guassians. $Q(\omega)$ can be the expression $\mathbb{E}_{z_1}[f(z_1,\omega)] + \mathbb{E}_{z_2}[f(z_2,\omega)] \geq 0$.
4. For a given $\omega$, is there a venn diagram for "$P(\omega)$ implies $Q(\omega)$"?

Comment: This only makes sense under the extra condition that the sets $\{\omega\mid P(\omega)\}$ and $\{\omega\mid Q(\omega)\}$ belong to $\mathcal F$. If not then the mentioned probabilities are not defined. So in absence of this condition the claim is *not* correct. In presence of this condition the claim is correct.

Comment: Although I am not very concerned about measurability here, I should have explicitly stated that the sets defined here belong to $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is correct and immediately follows from your note 2 (which is trivially true: $a\in\{x|P(x)\} \iff P(a)=\text{true} \implies Q(a)=\text{true} \iff a\in\{x|Q(x)\}$).

The Venn diagram for implication is the same as for subset, i.e., the set $\{x|P(x)\}$ being contained in the set $\{x|Q(x)\}$.